# What are IK bones, and what do they do?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9f-WVs3ghI) tutorial series, and he uses IK bones and the other types of bones that I've forgotten the name of (edit: since remembered, 'pole target'), a controlling bone under the foot and bone constraints.

What are IK bones, and what do they do?

Comment: Try and ask one question at a time, you're welcome to ask as many specific questions as you like in separate posts. If you can reduce your questions to something more specific, then this post may be reopened.

Comment: Have you look at the [docs](http://blender.org/manual/rigging/posing/inverse_kinematics.html) yet?

Comment: I probably should. I was being a bit lazy I suppose.